# $_FILES global variable not able to receive data sent from XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest, asyncfileupload

I am trying to upload a file to a folder in my server using XMLHttpRequest() and PHP.
Here is the HTML file `fu2.html`:

```
<form action="fu2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="loadFile()">
</form>
<script>
function loadFile() {

    var myFileList = document.getElementById("file").files;
    var fileToUpload = myFileList[0];
    alert(fileToUpload.name+","+fileToUpload.tmp_name);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'http://10.192.44.143/pgadmsn/fu2.php',false);
    xhr.send(fileToUpload);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
</script>
```

The php file `fu2.php` is :

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])){
$name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];

if (isset ($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {

    $location = 'uploads/';

    if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
        echo 'Uploaded';    
        }

        } else {
          echo 'please choose a file';
          }
    }
    else{
        echo "name not set";
    }
}
else echo "FILES not set!";
?>
```

There are 2 problems that I am facing:

1. In `alert(fileToUpload.name+","+fileToUpload.tmp_name);`, fileToUpload.tmp_name is coming to be undefined.
2. The major problem is that in fu2.php file where  `isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])` is evaluating to `false` because I am getting `FILES not set!` as `xhr.responseText`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: form_data.append('file', file_data);

Comment: Are u suggesting to use FormData object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the flaws :

1).  You're referencing an unexisting component name. It's *`$_FILES["file"]`* not *`$_FILES["fileToUpload"]`*

2).  Basically you're transmitting binary data to server via Ajax, you need mechanism to wrap the file into readable stream it can be achieved using [*`FormData`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object.

Here I fixed your codes:

fu.html

```
<form action="fu2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="loadFile()">
</form>
<script>
    function loadFile() {

        var myFileList = document.getElementById("file").files;
        var fileToUpload = myFileList[0];

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", fileToUpload);
        alert(fileToUpload.name);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", 'http://10.192.44.143/pgadmsn/fu2.php',false);
        xhr.send(fd);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
</script>
```

fu.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if (isset ($name)) {
        if (!empty($name)) {

            $location = 'uploads/';

            if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
                echo 'Uploaded';
            }

        } else {
            echo 'please choose a file';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "name not set";
    }
}
else echo "FILES not set!";
?>
```

Comment: Yeah bro, I was literally going nuts over this!

Comment: If I recall I saw your previous similar question, at the time I wanted to answer it but suddenly I got problem with my internet connection. :D

Comment: Oh! You did see that! As I said, I was literally going nuts over this for last 2 days! I guess the contents over net are a bit incomplete as for AJAX, all I could find was client-side stuff and they totally ignored the php code! If I used to get PHP code, then it would not be AJAX stuff!